# Does wrapping an lvalue in double curly braces create a temporary object that can be passed as an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following [compiles](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y3Yaber7W) on several different compilers including g++, clang, and MSVC, but I cannot figure out why:

```
#include <string>

class C {
    std::string m;
};

void Accept(C &&);

extern C c;

int main() {
    Accept({{c}});
}
```

The generated assembly code appears to show a call to the copy constructor of std::string before then calling Accept(), which I am assuming means that the compiler generated a call to class C's copy constructor. It therefore appears that using `{{c}}` as an argument to an rvalue reference parameter creates a temporary copy.

Is this an accurate interpretation? And if so, what C++ language feature or features are combining to allow `{{c}}` to create a temporary copy of `c`?

Comment: This behavior seems about right to me (i.e. I don't think you should find it surprising). The function call will (overload resolution considers how the function call would) initialize the parameter similarly to `C &&p{{c}}`. With a single brace pair, you're trying to initialize `p` from an lvalue and it fails. With two, I believe [this "fallback"](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.4.2) applies and treats the inner `{c}` as `C{c}`, which uses the copy constructor to produce a `C` prvalue which can materialize and be bound to `p`. I will let someone else fill in the gaps.

Comment: It's interesting that if the member variable is removed it fails to compile - live - https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f11Y5Ka79

Comment: @RichardCritten If you remove the member, then the class becomes aggregate as well and you can't aggregate-initialize an empty class with a non-empty braced-init-list. (There is an exception for a _single_ layer of braces in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#list-3.2, but not for nested braces.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How objects and references are initialized is specified in [dcl.init]. Specifically [[dcl.init]/16.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.1) says that initialization from braces instead of an expression is *list-initialization*.

How list-initialization is performed is specified in [[dcl.init.list]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#list-3). The first item in the chain that applies if the destination type is a reference is [[dcl.init.list]/3.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#list-3.9), which says that if the braced-init-list from which we initialize has exactly one element of a type that is reference-related to the destination type, then the reference is initialized from that element instead. So `Accept({c});` would initialize the reference in the function parameter by copy-initialization from `c`, causing it to bind directly to `c`.

You seem to expect this behavior to apply recursively if there are multiple layers of braces as well. However, in `{{c}}` the braced-init-list has exactly one element which itself is a braced-init-list `{c}` and braced-init-lists do not have a type (they are not expressions), so item [[dcl.init.list]/3.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#list-3.9) on the list can't apply. The following item [[dcl.init.list]/3.10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#list-3.10) then applies to reference destination types and  without further conditions specifies that a prvalue of the referenced type will be created and used to initialize the reference, meaning that a temporary object will be materialized that the function parameter will be bound to.

So nested braces will always initialize a reference with a temporary object, no matter what.

Specifically in your case it will end up as a temporary object initialized by a call to the implicitly-declared copy constructor of `C` which initializes the reference in the copy constructor's parameter with `{c}`, which in turn as described above means it binds directly to `c`, so that no further temporary will be created. It does not end up with aggregate initialization instead, because your class member is `private` and so the class is not an aggregate. If it was an aggregate (e.g. because you replace `class` with `struct`), then the initialization of the temporary would be ill-formed, because `std::string` can't be initialized from a `C`.

However, it seems that (at least in 2017) the C++ standard committee had some intentions to make your code ill-formed, see the note in [CWG issue 2319](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2319.html). The suggestion at the end of the issue description would also make the initialization of the temporary object in your call `Accept({{c}})` ill-formed for the non-aggregate case by disallowing the copy/move constructor to be used with nested braces.

Comment: This is fabulous! I added a bounty so I could reward it even more, but I won't be able to assign it for 24 hours, apparently.